# Unable to perform Undo CheckOut in ClearCase GUI

Tags: clearcase

When I am trying to do Undo Checkout through my ClearCase GUI, its showing me a error message as "Error Undoing the CheckOut for "E:\Views\Stream Name\File Name'.
    Lock on Versioned Object base "\ prevents operation uncheckout
    Unable to cancel Checkout for 'E:\Views\Stream Name\File Name' "

Please suggest me how can i solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure what is locked.

If it is the UCM project for instance, you need to run (or to ask your ClearCase admin to run) a [`cleartool unlock`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_unlock.htm):

```
cleartool unlock project:projectname@\pvobname
```

If this is a file/folder, it is possible it is locked by another user, in which case it can be unlocked at any time, allowing you to proceed.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to VonC's response - it's possible that the vob itself was locked for some reason.  Why would a vob overall be locked?  If it was being backed up, for example.  Someone may have run a "cleartool lock vob:myvob" or similar for some reason.  Then ran "cleartool unlock vob:myvob" afterwards.  I'd ask your clearcase admin for an explanation.